# Why aren't the titles of my items in a new product type not displaying at check out? - Commerce

Tags: commerce

I am building a store based on Commerce Kickstart.  I am using one of the original product types and two new product types that I created by essentially copying the field and display settings in the content type and product variations settings.  After a lot of fiddling around I have everything displaying properly, except in a couple of places in the check out process.

1) In the cart ( mysite.com/cart# ) the line items that I created display the sku of the item but not a "view product" link.  Where can I change this?

[image: cart display issue]

2) In the review order page ( mysite.com/checkout/ordernumber/review ) the line items of the product type that I created don't display the item title, while the item type that was there originally does.  Where can I change this?

[image: order review display issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  The issue was that my product had a title, but the variation didn't have the title field filled out.  So once I go to administration>products>find the failing product>edit, then I filled out the title field and saved.  Problem fixed.  I need to modify the way that I create the product so that both of these title fields get filled out upon product creation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a gotcha, but I suspect under user permissions, you may need to check the "View products of [type] type" permission for anonymous / authenticated users.

Comment: I tried this and I did find a bunch of permissions that needed to be checked, but it didn't solve my problem.  There are still no names showing up with my line items.  Any other thoughts David?